# unable to implicitly convert type error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a task to create a class `Student` and to create a method that pick the Students from an array only if their first name is before their last name alphabetically using LINQ query operators.  I've written the `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
     private string firstName;
     private string familyName;
     private int age;

    public Student(string firstName, string familyName, int age)
        : this()
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student()
    {
        firstName = "Dancho";
        familyName = "Mastikata";
        age = 24;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyName; }
        set { familyName = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
```

And then I coded this one:

```
public class StudentsManipulations
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Student[] students = new Student[6]{new Student("Georgi", "Milanov", 21      ),
                                            new Student("Ilko", "Pirgov", 30         ),
                                            new Student("Neboisha", "Yelenkovich", 34),
                                            new Student("Dimitar", "Berbatov", 32    ),
                                            new Student(                             ),
                                            new Student("Nikolai", "Bodurov", 24     )};

    }

    public static List<Student> StudentSortByFirstName(Student[] students)
    {
        List<Student> sortedStudents = from student in students 
             where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0 
             select student;

        return sortedStudents;
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately there is an error in where keyword, that I can't completely understand:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?).

Can you please help me understand what exactly is wrong?

Comment: I like your list of great BG footballers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method to enumerate results and put them into a list:

```
var query = from student in students
            where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0
            select student;

List<Student> sortedStudents = query.ToList();
```

Or in one statement:

```
List<Student> sortedStudents = (from student in students
                                where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0
                                select student).ToList();
```

Comment: Is that an anonymous type ?

Comment: no, `var` means an implicitly typed local variable. Read this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your error means that your fluent Linq is returning an `IEnumerable<Student>`, not the `List<Student>` you expect. You will need an additional `.ToList()` call or you can use the `IEnumerable<Student>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert your linq expression to a list:

```
List<Student> sortedStudents = (from student in students 
where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0 select student).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This query,

```
from student in students 
where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0 
select student
```

returns an `IEnumerable<Student>`.

If you want a `List<Student>`, then you should call `ToList()` on the resulting `IEnumerable<Student>`:

```
List<Student> sortedStudents = 
    (from student in students 
     where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0 
     select student)
    .ToList();
```

---

Note that as a general rule, LINQ queries are evaluated when the result is enumerated, and not before (this is called "lazy execution" or "lazy loading"). Calling `ToList()` however will execute the query immediately, enumerate the results, and populate a list.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `.ToList()` at the end of your statement.

This converts your Enumerable to a List

Answer (score 1):

Add [.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to your query:

```
List<Student> sortedStudents = (from student in students where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.FamilyName) < 0 select student).Tolist();
```